# Vector Merge Algorithm C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Having a hard time designing an efficient algorithm that accomplishes the following. If I start with a 2d vector A,

```
A = [1 2 3;
     2 3 4;
     5 6]
```

I want to take the rows that contain common elements and combine them (removing duplicates) resulting in 2d vector B:

```
B = [1 2 3 4;
     5 6]
```

I can accomplish this in Matlab, but am having a hard time in C++. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you're looking to find unique/distinct elements? Also, what do you mean by "rows"? You have one-dimensional arrays here...

Comment: Updated to represent 2d vector.

Comment: Are the input vectors sorted? Is it OK for the output vectors to be sorted if the input vectors are not sorted?

Comment: Sorting can be used wherever and whenever required. Ordering of values is not important, so long as they end up in the required rows.

Comment: This doesnt make sense. why does `4` end up on the first row?

Comment: Because row 2 has elements in common with row 1. I am looking to combine rows with any common elements such that the remaining rows in B are completely unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me with your example matrix. It looks like a lot of code, but there are functions just for the example and for debugging purpose.

```
void disp( const std::vector< int >& a )
{
    for ( const auto item : a )
    {
        std::cout << item;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void disp( const std::vector< std::vector< int > >& matrix )
{
    for ( const auto& row : matrix )
    {
        disp( row );
    }
}

// I think there shall be some easier way for this.
bool hasCommonElements( const std::vector< int >& aVector1, const std::vector< int >& aVector2 )
{
    for ( const auto item1 : aVector1 )
    {
        for ( const auto item2 : aVector2 )
        {
            if ( item1 == item2 )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void makeAllElementsUnique( std::vector< int >& aRow )
{
    std::sort( aRow.begin(), aRow.end() );
    aRow.erase( std::unique( aRow.begin(), aRow.end() ), aRow.end() );
}

void mergeRowsWithCommonValues( std::vector< std::vector< int > >& aMatrix )
{
    for ( auto it = aMatrix.begin(); it != aMatrix.end(); ++it )
    {
        auto it2 = it + 1;
        while ( it2 != aMatrix.end() )
        {
            if ( hasCommonElements( *it, *it2 ) )
            {
                (*it).insert( (*it).end(), (*it2).begin(), (*it2).end() ); // Merge the rows with the common value(s).
                makeAllElementsUnique( (*it) );

                it2 = aMatrix.erase( it2 ); // Remove the merged row.
            }
            else
            {
                ++it2;
            }
        }
    }
}

void example()
{
    std::vector< std::vector< int > > matrix;

    matrix.push_back( { 1, 2, 3 } );
    matrix.push_back( { 2, 3, 4 } );
    matrix.push_back( { 5, 6 } );

    disp( matrix );
    mergeRowsWithCommonValues( matrix );
    disp( matrix );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to develop this. I'll test it out once I get home and let you know how it goes. Appreciate it!

Comment: @KyleBooth It worked for so I hope it will be good for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own attempt, kinda messy, I know.

```
    int index2 = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int tracker = 0;
    int insert = 0;
    // Loop over all rows
    while (index2 < A.size()){
        // Check if vector is empty. If so, copy the first row in.
        if (B.empty()){
            B.push_back(A[index2]);
            index2++;
            cout<<"Hit an empty.\n";
        }
        // If vector not empty, do the complicated stuff.
        else if (!B.empty()){
            for (int i = 0; i < A[index2].size(); i++){ // element in A
                for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++){ // row in B
                    for (int k = 0; k < B[j].size(); k++){ // element in row in B
                        if (A[index2][i] == B[j][k]){
                            rowIndex = j;
                            tracker = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // If tracker activated, we know there's a common element.
            if (tracker == 1){
            cout<<"Hit a positive tracker.\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < A[index2].size(); i++){ // element in A 
                    for (int j = 0; j < B[rowIndex].size(); j++){ // element in B at rowIndex
                        if (A[index2][i] != B[rowIndex][j])
                            insert++;
                            cout<<"Hit an insert increment.\n";
                    }
                    if (insert == B[rowIndex].size()){
                        cout<<"Hit an insert.\n";
                        B[rowIndex].push_back(A[index2][i]);
                        }
                    insert = 0;
                }   
            index2++;
            }else{
                B.push_back(A[index2]);
                index2++;
                cout<<"Hit a zero tracker.\n";
            }
        }       
    tracker = 0;
    }
```

Comment: you will gain vastly in clarity, simplicity by implementing 2 methods : `std::vector union(std::vector a, std::vector b)`, `std::vector  intersection(std::vector a, std::vector b)`. Bonus for using the stl build in function to implement those.

Comment: @UmNyobe Dang. Just looked these up and they're really nice. Will definitely try implement them. Thanks!